# How to make an already loaded img not load again in angular

Tags: angular

this is my custom image viewer

```
   <div class="slider">
      <ul>
        <li *ngFor="let image of images; let idx = index">
          <img [src]="image.contentLink"
               [ngClass]="{'current': idx === currentImageIdx}"
               (click)="currentImageIdx=idx"
               class="slider-image"
               alt="image">
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    
    <div class="image-viewer">
      <div class="image-viewer-content">
        <img [src]="images[currentImageIdx].contentLink"
             alt="image" class="full-screen"
        >
      </div>
    
    </div>
```

When I switch between img1.jpg and img2.jpg the browser requests both 1 and 2 images when I return to img1.jpg , the browser downloads again img1.jpg
How do I fix re-downloading img?

Comment: Where do you store the images? When you request them with a static and not changing url, then usually your browser should take care caching